# how to echo std output exactly in C

Tags: c, shell

I'm making essentially a terminal wrapper. I want my program to read from `stdin`, and for any inputs that come in, echo it EXACTLY the way it is, even if it's wrong.

Right now, I'm doing:

```
        FILE *output = popen(buffer, "r");
        memset(buffer, '\0', BUFF_SIZE * 2);
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), output) != 0)
        {
            printf("%s", buffer);
            memset(buffer, '\0', BUFF_SIZE * 2);
        }
        pclose(output);
        }
```

where I'm calling shell commands using `popen`, but in certain situations, for example, when the command is not found, the output returned by using `popen` won't be exactly the same compared to when using the terminal without the wrapper. For example, if I input `$ asd`, linux terminal will return

```
No command 'asd' found, but there are 24 similar ones
asd: command not found
```

whereas `popen` will return:

```
sh: 1: asd not found
```

I would like to have the default terminal response rather than what `popen` returns, would this be possible? If so, how?

Comment: right, I realized that but where can I find the shell terminal is using?

Comment: sorry to leave your comment hanging on its own -- i deleted my initial comment when i realized you have a rather large amount of learning to do.  honestly I think the best approach is to do lots of research on the internet, including looking at existing code, rather than asking here every time you hit a problem.  you'll end up in a better place, since there are a number of interesting issues you'll have to understand, and understanding the principles will be more valuable than just having working code you don't fully understand.  good luck!

Comment: Shells behave differently in interactive and non-interactive mode. You can force bash to run in interactive mode by running it with the `-i` option. This documentation describes how interactive shell mode differs from non-interactive mode: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior . That said, you will very likely run into trouble forcing interactive behavior.

Comment: `memset(buffer, '\0', BUFF_SIZE * 2);` are not needed and may be harmful as used here.

Comment: The user's default login shell will be in the `SHELL` environment variable.

Comment: Code will not work if null characters are read,  Consider `fgetc()`.

Comment: **echo it EXACTLY the way it is, even if it's wrong.** Your code doesn't echo the input, it executes it as a command.

Comment: @Barmar I want to echo the output after execution

Comment: If that's what you want, you should say it more clearly in the question.

Comment: Some of the output is probably going to standard error — error messages are mainly written to standard error because that's what it is for.  You don't seem to be redirecting that.  You're actually setting yourself a very difficult task.